# listSearch by videoCategoryId falls with error , until today it worked

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Today I've encountered error with php-code, it worked for six months, and now it falls

```
$listResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch(
        'id,snippet', 
        array(
            'channelId' => 'UCeP5_pUXbKpMlR-_mVQTCSg', 
            'maxResults'=>3, 
            'order'=>'date', 
            'type'=>'video', 
            'videoCategoryId'=>'UCeP5_pUXbKpMlR-_mVQTCSg.jNQXAC9IVRw'
        )
);
```

I've checked it with "youtube try'it" service and get error http://take.ms/WXSBj
Please!! Help me! Need Assistance!)

## UPDATE 1:  This is API BUG:  do you know how to get category videos via another method ?

***and problem is only in parameter videoCategoryId***

[image]

Comment: This is definitely a bug with the API.  I would file a bug report with Google: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?q=label:APi-YouTube

Comment: thanks for link, do you know how to get category videos via another method ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably in video category id values, 
I've get that values via method $youtube->channelSections->listChannelSections 
It is popularVideos. 
So, my code works without specifying them thanks to "order = date" parameter.